# Can I voxelize 3D set of points without reconstructing surface first?

Tags: rendering, performance, voxelization

I have huge point cloud data I want to render them at interactive frame frate. Process I know is

1.point cloud data

2.triangulate it using delnauy or other triangulation algo

3.surface voxelization for mesh

4.volume tracing ti render

But triangulation process is very very slow. Can I somehow voxelize my point cloud directly?
I am newbie to voxelization.

Comment: Can you not subdivide your world into a 3d grid and if any grid has >= 1 point inside it, it can be made into a voxel?

Comment: You could use a fullscreen triangle and raymarch it. There's lots of tutorials about that. And iirc it's the preferred method.

Comment: Why do you *need* voxels to begin with? Can't you just render the points themselves (possibly with some adaptive point size)?